# Email Subtitle - Is there an easy way to do this?

Tags: html, css, email

I am using a header and footer which I upload to my companies campaign manager program. This header and footer cannot be changed. But I want to change the subtitle which appears on some email clients after the Subject next to the unopened email (which currently has the first line of the email which is "click here if email has not loaded"). Is there anyway I can change the subtitle through the content beneath the header? If not is there a way I can have a subtitle which is not "click here" which does not appear directly on my email.

Answer (score 0):

I really don't see a way to do this without being able to edit the email header contents (which is where I assume this "Click here" text is located).

In the past to correct a similar issue, I have either moved that text down farther into the content or footer of the email, or replaced it with an image (having `alt` text to show in case images do not load). The latter choice is a matter of personal preference and probably not ideal. That said, however, these solutions require changing the header.

Answer (score 0):

To change it you need access to the Header Contents

Answer (score 0):

To change the preview of your email you can only use a hack. As it will always display the first lines of your email, you'll have to edit your email template to start it with whatever catchphrase you want in your email preview.

However, I'm pretty sure you don't want to add an extra sentence that will display before your email so here is the trick: **use a 1px by 1px transparent gif with your catchphrase in the ALT tag**.

```
<img alt="YOUR CATCHPHRASE" src="your-transparent-gif.gif" width="1" height="1" border="0">
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, though it did not seem to work for me annoyingly, so I used a slightly ugly coding that did the trick. I made the text extremely small and the same color as the background so it did not appear. This then appeared on the subtitle preview without causing issues to my email.